# how to get deleted posts in facebook graph or who deleted it when i'm group admin

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

how to get deleted post if applicable in facebook? using FQL or Graph api
or when i'm in a group admin .. how to know who deleted posts !!
i did search google and facebook and didn't find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a post is deleted it is not available through the API anymore.
The Facebook API (either fql or GRAPH) does not provide any support to get this administrative information.

Answer (score 0):

The one that initially worked is through the mbasic mode. I tried making a script for the desktop and mobile version of Facebook at first but the delete buttons generate unpredictable POS values when not refreshed. I encountered some glitches with mbasic along the way so I knew I had to make the desktop hack work.

So let's go and clean that spam-infested Facebook group of yours.

Step 1
Download the iMacros for Chrome extension.

Step 2
The extensions can be seen at the top right corner of the browser. Click on the iMacros for Chrome icon to run.

Step 3
Go to the Record tab just below the yellowish tree pane.

Step 4
For mbasic.facebook.com,

Click on the Record Macro button then click on the Stop button. The iMacros Editor will pop out.

Replace the code inside the editor with:

SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

WAIT SECONDS=3

TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:SeeMorePosts
WAIT SECONDS=3

TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:*Comment*
WAIT SECONDS=3

TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Delete
WAIT SECONDS=3

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/a/delete.php?* ATTR=*
WAIT SECONDS=4
Hit Save As & Close button. Rename the script to something like mbasic.iim Make sure you got that extension correctly.

Step 5
For www.facebook.com,

Click on the Record Macro button again then click on the Stop button.

Replace the code inside the editor with:

SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

URL GOTO=https://www.facebook.com/groups/URL
WAIT SECONDS=3

TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:u_0_2*
WAIT SECONDS=2

TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:DeleteFile
WAIT SECONDS=2

TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:DeletePost
WAIT SECONDS=2

TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Delete
WAIT SECONDS=2
As you can see from the code, there is a URL. Change it to your group's URL

Hit Save As & Close button. Rename the script to something like www.iim Make sure you got that extension correctly as well.

Step 6
Go to the Play tab. Set the Max value to 999.

Step 7
Go to your facebook group's url and make sure your language is set to English. Example: mbasic.facebook.com/groups/URL or www.facebook.com/groups/URL

Step 8
Select the appropriate script from the yellowish tree pane.

Hit the Play Loop button. See the magic happens.
[search more](https://searchrace.com)